# how to prevent form to render to the new page after submit form?

Tags: javascript

```
function post(url, fields) {
  //create a <form> element.
  var p = document.createElement('form');
  //construct the form
  p.action = url;
  p.innerHTML = fields;
  p.target = '_self';
  p.method = 'post';
  //append the form to the current page.
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  //submit the form
  p.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

I also try this way. But none of them is working. Whenever the form is submitted, it will render the page. I need to stop the form render the page after submit. Thanks for any help!
[image: Another try]

Comment: try stopPropogation function

Comment: When you call `submit()` on the `<form>` element, it submits the form. I think you want an AJAX solution

Answer (score 1):

try post method rather than submitting form

```js
function post(url, fields) {
  $.post(url,{fields: fields} ,function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
}
```

```js
function post(url, fields) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(fields));
}
```